# Not displaying Category and subcategory from woocommerce Pluign

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have installed woocommerce pluign but when I created categories that page is blank I want to display subcategories in that page and after we click on subcategory that should display all products under that subcategory.Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
my design as follow particular category in that page all subcategories show display  then I will click or select 1 subcategory then that in that subcategory page all products should display.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change one option.

Follow steps:

- Go to "**Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Catalog**"
- Choose "**Show subcategories**" in "**Category display**" option
- Click "**Publish**" button

Comment: its not displaying subcategories it displaying products

Comment: url is as follows  /product-category/fresh-range/